# compare two columns in different tables sql

Tags: sql, join, select, sql-insert

We have two different tables with two same columns. One column has a constant value in both but one column may have different values. How can we compare these two tables according to the constant columns. The goal is to update a different column.

My code Management studio is :

```sql
SELECT [ModernizationCode],[ReceiptSerial]
FROM [Backup].[dbo].[Distribution]
INNER JOIN [Backup].[dbo].[combineareas]
ON [Distribution].[ModernizationCode] = [combineareas].[ModernizationCode]
AND [Distribution].[ReceiptSerial] = [combineareas].[ReceiptSerial]
WHERE [combineareas].[ReceiptSerial] <> [Distribution].[ReceiptSerial]
```

and my error

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Ambiguous column name 'ModernizationCode'.
> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Ambiguous column name 'ReceiptSerial'.

and I cannot fix it.

Comment: Did you tried anything ? how your table looks like ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show some sample data, required output and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear but i'll try. Let assume columns with constant values named 'id' and other column named 'col' in both tables, seems you are trying to copy 'col' values from first table to another. So query might looks like:

```
 update table2 t2
 set t2.col = (select t1.col 
                 from table1 t1
                 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: i used that code like                                                                                                    UPDATE [Distribution] 
 set [Distribution].[ReceiptSerial] = (select [combineareas].[ReceiptSerial] 
 from [combineareas] 
 where [Distribution].[ModernizationCode] = [combineareas].[ModernizationCode])                                                                                   error eccoured below:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Seems like **[combineareas].[ModernizationCode]** isn't unique, isn't it? So what actually are you trying to do? What value **[Distribution].[ReceiptSerial]** should be setted to if there is several rows with same **[combineareas].[ModernizationCode]**?

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand what you are going to do because the question is not clear but the error is very obvious.

When you JOIN two or more tables that have columns with same name then you should specify the ALIAS or NAME of tables. (Except the time using * in select expression.)

In your query the columns `[ModernizationCode]` and `[ReceiptSerial]` both exists in two of your tables. Then add table name before them to avoid the raised error.

```
SELECT combineareas.[ModernizationCode],combineareas.[ReceiptSerial]
FROM [Backup].[dbo].[Distribution]
inner JOIN
[Backup].[dbo].[combineareas]
ON [Distribution].[ModernizationCode] = [combineareas].[ModernizationCode]
and [Distribution].[ReceiptSerial] = [combineareas].[ReceiptSerial]
WHERE [combineareas].[ReceiptSerial] <> [Distribution].[ReceiptSerial]
```

Another fact: The code I have corrected have no error but also returns no record. When joining on a columns, It means they must be equal; So they never can be different (Referring the condition in WHERE clause)